# How to bind usb encoder to keyboard keys

Tags: usb

I currently have an arcade stick I made a while ago, which I want to use in a project with my Pi, which will run a simple scratch project. The Arcade Stick connects to the Pi through USB, and I can't find any way to bind the Arcade Buttons to keyboard inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure how you'd detect inputs from the joystick, but you can probably use a python library like [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html) or [PiBorg](https://github.com/piborg/Gamepad). You could then read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564851/how-to-generate-keyboard-events-in-python) to see a few ways you can emulate a keystroke. In the end, you would have a simple python script that's running in the background, which would convert your joystick movements to keystrokes. If you'd like you could create a service and have the python script automatically run at bootup with systemd.